# doGet is not called with "state" parameter name, got server error

Tags: google-apps-script

since few days, when I try to invoke all scripts as service with parameter "state", I receive a strange "Google Docs has encountered a server error", method doGet is not ever called!

Please, can you confirm that something is changed?

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a simple apps script with only getMethod

   ```
       function doGet(e) {
         Logger.log("doGet");
         MailApp.sendEmail("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "Log", Logger.getLog());


     var app = UiApp.createApplication();

     return app;
   }
   ```
2. Publish the service
3. Invoke the script from browser passing "state" parameter

   https://sites.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbwrrSzd5PM07HgmuOSE1UsXxO9MmGTEOEwvXQC1&state=sample_parameter
4. The server returns error:

   ```
       Google Docs has encountered a server error. If reloading the page doesn't help, please contact us.

   To discuss this or other issues, visit the Google Docs Help forum. To see the list of known problems, check the Google Docs Known Issues page.

   Sorry, and thanks for your help!
   - The Google Docs Team
   ```

I've also opened [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1358)

Thanks all,
Francesco

**EDIT:** [Issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1358) has been fixed! Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating the issue report was the right thing to do. But note that this will probably not be "fixed" in the way you want. They will probably just include in the documentation that you can not use a parameter named "state".

The solution is just to use a different name, e.g. myState or something else. Not very annoying or difficult to do IMHO.

Comment: Tested again and still not working. Edited first post with steps to reproduce the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to Issue 1336 ( http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1336 ) although that issue has been fixed. Can you try authorizing your script.

Comment: Script authorized but no change, issue is still there.
I think that problem is exactly in name of request parameter. It seems that Google Apps Script does not like parameter with name "state".
Very annoying bug. I use this name because of OAuth2.0 handshake (see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer), no way to change it.